# error session_decode(): Session is not active (nginx/php-fpm)

Tags: php

Having trouble decoding the following error in the nginx logs. What can I do to get more details about this error?

```
2017/01/09 07:11:01 [error] 14939#14939: *137 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: session_decode(): Session is not active. You cannot decode session data in /srv/www/forward-staging.org/current/symphony/lib/core/class.session.php:198
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: GenericErrorHandler::handler(2, 'session_decode(...', '/srv/www/forwar...', 198, Array)
#1 /srv/www/forward-staging.org/current/symphony/lib/core/class.session.php(198): session_decode(NULL)
#2 /srv/www/forward-staging.org/current/symphony/lib/core/class.session.php(162): Session::unserialize(NULL)
#3 [internal function]: Session::write('177b1ef34bb1346...', 'sym-|a:0:{}')
#4 [internal function]: session_write_close()
#5 {main}
  thrown in /srv/www/forward-staging.org/current/symphony/lib/core/class.session.php on line 198" while reading upstream, client: 10.128.12.7, server: forward-staging.org, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm-forward.sock:", host: "forward-staging.org"
```

Running:
PHP 7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
nginx version: nginx/1.11.8
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: well, any clue on php version, also have you checked permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try first to fix the date of system

```
    #1 /srv/www/forward-staging.org/current/symphony/lib/core/class.session.php(198): session_decode(NULL)
#2 /srv/www/forward-staging.org/current/symphony/lib/core/class.session.php(162): Session::unserialize(NULL)
#3 [internal function]: Session::write('177b1ef34bb1346...', 'sym-|a:0:{}')
```

Comment: what points to the date being wrong? I just checked and it seems right to me.